# Why didn't I get a reputation bonus?

Tags: support, reputation

I associated my account, but I'm still at 1.  Why didn't I get a reputation bonus?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As stated by Jeff Atwood [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/account-association-between-websites):

> There is a +100 rep boost for every
>   association you make if either the
>   source or target account has at least
>   200 reputation.

So as you didn't have 200 reputation already (I see you have 77 now on SO), you didn't get the +100 boost.

Comment: So what happens if you get 200 shortly after associating? Do we really have to jump through the hoops of dissociating and re-associating—assuming it’s possible?

Comment: @Synetech: don't know... guess you'll have to test it out ;-)

Comment: I don't think you can de-associate, or I would have tried it (something went wrong when I associated and I only got the bonus on SO not on MSO.)