# The FAQ should add clarifying detail about the +100 account association bonus

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, linked-accounts

I know we don't want bloated, off-putting FAQs that make the system seem too complex to new users, but we also want to ensure that they tend to answer any questions that are, well... frequently asked. And to that point, there seems to be [a](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35090/no-bonus-on-stackoverflow-when-merging-accounts-with-serverfault) [prevalence](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5983/should-all-linked-accounts-get-the-100-bonus) [of](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35033/bonus-points-for-merging-accounts) [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50508/no-bonus-points-on-linking-the-accounts) [on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10730/why-didnt-i-get-a-reputation-bonus) [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57790/are-the-bonuses-still-given-to-who-registers-to-more-than-one-stack-exchange-site) related to:

1. **Whether there's a minimum point level
   to get the bonus** (yes, 200)
2. **Whether you get multiple +100 bonuses on a site for associating multiple
   other sites that meet the minimum**
   (no, you can only get a total of 100 points for associating one or more accounts that have 200+)
3. **Why someone didn't get it for an associated account that hit 200 after association.**  (You have to have 200 at the time of association, so you need to break, and then re-establish the association to get it in that case.)

Given the amount of confusion, it might be worth ensuring that all family sites clearly address the three points above in the FAQ.

I'm aware that all that info is currently available in numerous other places, but I think it causes confusion often enough that it merits clearer coverage in the FAQ.

Comment: Why not make this question the FAQ proposal?  CW it and move half the body into an answer and we're all set.

Comment: There has been no activity here for over a year. Instead of trying to revive this question, I've edited the answers to this post into [the reputation FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work). Please vote to close this post as a duplicate of the FAQ.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Good idea!

Adding to the FAQ as:

> If you are an experienced [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) user with **200** or more reputation on at least one site, you will receive a starting **+100** reputation bonus to get you past basic new user restrictions. This will happen automatically on all current Stack Exchange sites where you have an account, and on any other Stack Exchange sites at the time you log in.