# You can't choose which SE account gets the +100 bonus?

Tags: support, reputation, linked-accounts

Just to get clarification, you can't choose which SE account gets the +100 bonus? So if I create a new account on one of the SE sites using the same OpenID then I'm automatically forced to link my old SE account (with 200+ rep) and avail the +100 on the new account and *not* on the older account? Or both accounts get awarded +100 rep?

Comment: related: [The FAQs should add clarifying detail to the +100 bonus for associating accounts with 200+ rep.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57897/the-faqs-should-add-clarifying-detail-to-the-100-bonus-for-associating-accounts)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Each* account gets the +100 bonus when there is at least *one other* account with 200+ rep

Comment: And each account gets it only once?

Comment: @Ashish: exactly, only once no matter how many other accounts reach 200 rep