# Didn't got starting +100 reputation bonus?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, association-bonus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Just created an account on a new SE site, where's my +100 rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125439/just-created-an-account-on-a-new-se-site-wheres-my-100-rep)

I am having more than 200 reputation on SO and MSO. 
[image: assocition]

I have made 2 new accounts on  [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/users/114144/somnath-muluk) and [wordpress.stackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/14167/somnath-muluk).

So this sites should get +100 reputation according to [rule](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60524/you-cant-choose-which-se-account-gets-the-100-bonus).
I got +100 bonus for sites which I have created before. But didn't got for these two sites.

So why didn't got starting +100 reputation bonus? Are some sites exceptions?

Comment: This has been happening a lot lately

Comment: I got +100 bonus for sites which I have created before instantly as I log in 1st time. Is there any official declaration this much maximum time will be required to get +100 reputation bonus?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125439/155190 and the first answer to see if that helps and explains things a bit more

Comment: In that answer `Nick Craver` told that he had deployed fix. So let's see when my number comes.