# Account association not giving +100

Tags: bug, status-completed, linked-accounts

A user on the [Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) ran into a [problem associating accounts](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/265/73) -- he wasn't getting +100 for associating with his other accounts (even though he [definitely should](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/2650?tab=accounts)):

[image: User's flair on Unix]

I tested it by making a new account on [Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/395?tab=accounts), and associating it with my other  accounts, but it stayed at 1 too:

[image: My flair on Physics]

Something appears to be wrong with the +100 rep bonus for associating with another account

---

**Edit**: For maximum confusion, I found that creating an account on *another* SE I hadn't been on caused me to get the association bonus on the *first* site. I signed up for Physics, got nothing, signed up for OnStartups, got the association bonus on Physics but nothing on OnStartups, and then signed up for GIS and got the association bonus for OnStartups (GIS is still at 1). I'm seeing "user associated account: Unix <-> SO" entries in my Unix account history, which I think is wrong since these associations had nothing to do with either of those, but I don't know enough about that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Subtle.

There's a bug in some new associations code (that went out last night) that prevents the current account from gaining the association bonus.  This has been fixed on dev, and <del>should go out tonight</del> has now been deployed.

The work around for now is to establish the association from one of your other accounts (may require clearing before hand).

Comment: Hey... Today I've just signed up for one more StackExchange site, and I got no +100 rep bonus. I needed to unlink and relink accounts in order to get it. So... I think this bug is not really fixed.

Comment: @Denilson - another issue has been reported, which will be fixed in today's code push.  Should be about an hour.  It will require affected accounts to re-associate.

Comment: I think there still is a problem with the 100+ awards. My son linked his three accounts today, but got no 100 points. I let him unlink them once more, and re-link them again but still no 100 points. Account = http://math.stackexchange.com/users/7820/kevindl.

Comment: @Edelcom Your son doesn't have >200 on his existing account, which is needed to trigger the bonus.  @Kevin Montrose I am, however, experiencing a problem with the reputation bonus despite having >200 on one account: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/87250/200-reputation-on-area51-not-granting-bonus-to-other-stackexchange-sites

Answer (score 1):

You need to click the `clear all associations` button on the accounts tab first and then re-associate all the accounts. After that, any further associations should know better.

Comment: This is for an account I just made twenty minutes ago, I shouldn't need to reassociate

Comment: @Michael: I actually just reproduced it myself on boardgames, but it looks like Kevin has it fixed.

Comment: I just signed up at physics.stackexchange.com this morning, and I had this problem: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/122 Since I have 14 accounts, I'd rather not unassociate them all unless it's the only way to fix them.

Comment: @Steve: The workaround was to initiate the association **from the >200 account**, but according to Kevin's answer it shouldn't be causing problems anymore.

Comment: I don't think it's fixed, as I just signed up for a new account on physics today (Nov 16th), associated it with my SO account, and I got no bonus. I'll try the workaround, but will "clear all associations" just break the link from physics to everything else? Or will it break all links between every account? Regardless, it looks like there's still a bug.

Comment: Just an FYI, I fixed my problem by unlinking and relinking like people said, but my problem occurred when creating a fresh account at physics.se.org AFTER the bug was supposed to be fixed, so it might still be an issue.

Comment: @yhw41: The bug is still there - my son has just re-associated his three accounts, but still does not receive the 100+ points.

Comment: @Edelcom: leave a comment on [the other answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/70147/account-association-not-giving-100/70149#70149) for @Kevin with a link to the user account that won't associate. As one of the developers, he might be able to see what's not happening.

Comment: @Edelcom: Please know that [he](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/7820/kevindl) should only get the bonus if _at least one_ of his accounts has > 200 rep. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57897/the-faqs-should-add-clarifying-detail-to-the-100-bonus-for-associating-accounts) for some discussion since I can't find the FAQ on it right now.