# Mathematics +100 Rep for associating with Mathematics?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, association

This question is a two parter.

First, for some reason I got a +100 rep boost on all my accounts because of math.stackexchange despite the fact that My accounts have been associated for weeks without the rep boost (except for physics during the private beta). Is this a new decision?

Second, If it is intentional, I assume that getting 100 rep for associating my math.stackexchange account *with* my math.stackexchange account is a bug. Sorry that I couldn't grab a screen shot before clearing the notice but I had a banner that said "+100 Rep for associating Mathematics with Mathematics" or something similiar.

Comment: I also just realized that this might have been better placed at meta.stackexchange but I only just learned of its existence, my apologies. However, the +100 rep happened on SO as well so I guess not all is lost!

Comment: actually, this here is the right site. Meta Stack Exchange is for the old Stack Exchange 1.0 sites (where people paid to get their own sites about whatever they wanted) that are dying out.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably caused by [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70147/account-association-not-giving-100) bug that was fixed recently.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the message displayed, not the association bonus itself.

It has been fixed on dev, and will probably go out later today.

Comment: Well I got the 100 Points... Or do you mean that the message should have been different?

Comment: @crasic - you were supposed to get the bonus, but the message was buggy.  The message has been fixed (or will be, once we deploy new code anyway).

Comment: I recently associated with the boardgames stack exchange site, and didn't receive the +100 bonus. Same bug?