# Did not get +100 reputation for associating account

Tags: bug, status-completed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linked account didn't get 100 rep points](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50503/linked-account-didnt-get-100-rep-points)

My account here, on meta, never got the 100 reputation from associating with existing accounts. According to the FAQ, it should. According to the accounts tab, my profile here is associated with my profiles on Stack Overflow, ServerFault and Area51.

I don't remember what my reputation on any of those sites was or when I created this account. Does the bonus only apply if I first log in after reaching 200 reputation on another site?

Edit: Clearing associations and re-associating did assign the +100 rep bonus per Popular Demand's suggestion

Comment: I was coming to post the same question. This has happened on E&R SO. http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/165/230

Comment: If you associate before you earn the bonus, you have to disassociate and reassociate to get it.

Comment: @Popular The duplicate is from six months ago and is [status-completed], so this is apparently a new problem. And at least in Kortuk's case the account was just made today, so reassociating shouldn't matter

Comment: Looks like you got 100 points on all your other SE accounts.  Except meta.  Bass ackwards.

Comment: @Michael This sounds, then, similar to [what happened a few days ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70147/account-association-not-giving-100). Except not quite the same.

Comment: @Grace Yeah, I mentioned that to Kortuk when he brought it up on chat; possibly they re-broke the same thing

Comment: @Michael, hm, I guess this was not the same issue I thought it was. Since the OP said "existing," I figured the associations were just old. My mistake.

Comment: Clearing associations and re-associating did assign the +100 rep bonus per Popular Demand's suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I thought at first this was a bug in the new associations code (there have been a few [maybe more than a few...]) but the dates are all wrong.

I'm going to mark this as status-completed, because the code responsible is now gone.

Comment: ~ discussion in chat.meta.SO/tavern but I don't think it's fixed. I just created a new English.SE and I've not gotten the instant +100. Is there an account provision delay?

Comment: @drachenstern - there are some known issues with associations, another set of fixes are going out today.

Comment: and the response in the chatroom was either "disassociate and reassociate or wait" so I opted for wait. I'm in no rush, just thought I would offer feedback on a newly created site user.

Comment: I should probably followup that today when I finally got around to logging back into E.SE and meta.E.SE I had my +100. Thanks again to all you guys and gals.