# Bonus rep on new SE accounts not being awarded automatically

Tags: bug, status-completed

Before any new site would get +100 rep so I could use the core features.

Now I have to link them, then disassociate them and relink them to get the +100 rep

Is this intended site behavior?

Comment: This may be the same as what was reported in [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70351/did-not-get-100-reputation-for-associating-account) and/or [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70147/account-association-not-giving-100).

Comment: No, none of the "work arrounds" actually work. I have to disassociate and re-associate on each new site. This is not for old accounts, and I have had more than 200 rep on my GameDev account for a while now. This is a bug, and I think it should be looked in to.

Comment: Oh, just coincidence, then. +1.

Answer (score 2):

There was a regression earlier this week with regards to auto-association and the +100 rep bonus.

It has been fixed, and I've gone through and fixed the bonus on all the affected accounts I can find.  There may still be some out there, but a simple clear/re-associate will grant the bonus as expected.