# Creating account on Stack Overflow through OpenId Vs Google Accounts

Tags: discussion, reputation, openid, association-bonus

Why is it that, if you create an account with OpenId you get 100 reputation but if you create an account in Google Account or other OpenId provider you just get 1 reputation?

Isn't this unfair?

I tried to search for the question but couldn't find one, sorry if this is a duplicate question.

Comment: Because google is evil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get 1 reputation regardless of the method used to sign-up an account.  The 100 reputation bonus is for new accounts where you already have an existing associated account with over 200 reputation.

Here is more detail about the 100 bonus rep: [The FAQ should add clarifying detail about the +100 account association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57897/the-faqs-should-add-clarifying-detail-to-the-100-bonus-for-associating-accounts)

Answer (score 4):

The +100 reputation is a bonus for having at least one account at 200 reputation in the same association. It's based not on any specific provider, only that all of the accounts share the same OpenId.

The reason that the Google account would not have +100 is because it is not the same OpenId endpoint you used for all of the other accounts. Thus, with no way to tell that it should be associated with the accounts, it will not earn +100. You'll need to switch it to the other OpenId, or switch all of the other accounts over to Google.