# If possible, please add rep from bonuses to the bottom section of reputation recalc page

Tags: support, status-completed, reputation-recalc

I was trying to use [Trigger Reputation Recalc](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) page and noticed that there was a difference of 101 points between *total rep* and *rep this year*. I know that I started with 1 point but it took sometime for me to understand why there was a difference of 100 points. Scrolling to the top section, I found that I got 100 points from bonuses.

If it is not too much work, would it be possible to add `rep from bonuses` above the *total rep* line? I have shown a sample display in the screenshot below.

[image: Reputation Recalc]

Comment: What does this bonus means? where did you get it from?

Comment: @gdoron: [Read this MSO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57897/the-faq-should-add-clarifying-detail-about-the-100-account-association-bonus) to know more about association bonus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty trivial change and adds some clarity to the report...so it will start appearing in your reputation report after the next build.